# ODK, Formhub, Enketo pulldata command

Tags: xls, xforms, odk

I am attempting to create an xls form that uses the "pulldata" command to reference data uploaded in a csv document. ODK provides an example of this here: [link](http://opendatakit.org/downloads/download-info/sample-preloading-form/).

When I try to upload their example to a website that allows for the hosting of xlsforms via Enketo (Formhub.org or Ona.io) I get the message "Function "{}pulldata" does not exist." However, Ona.io claims that they DO have this functionality in their blog: [link 2](http://blog.ona.io/general/2014/06/02/preload-csv-data.html).

It seems that "pulldata" and the related "search" commands are not supported by Enketo. I imagine they do work in ODK Collect on Android devices.

I would like to use these functions on web forms (not Android devices). Is there a way to get them to work in Enketo or an alternative for hosting xlsforms / x forms online?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Pulldata() is now supported in the new Enketo app (Enketo Express). It just requires the form to be transformed with a version of pyxform (XLSForm) after September 5th 2015.